# Ant build for 2 different versions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, build

This is my situation: I'm developing a java midlet application for J2me and Blackberry. Most of the code is generalised. Now I'm looking into a way of quickly switching between building the J2me application and the Blackberry application.

The main advantage would be not having to change the platform specific code (which isn't that much in the end). Maybe an extra ant build is a good way to achieve this? Could I hear some opinions on this?

Comment: Or is ist better to solve this problem on the level of code by checking variables which indicate the type of application?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest splitting the source tree up into 3 separate projects; one for the common code and one for each of the two platforms. You should be able to refactor your code so that none of the code for one platform has any overlap with the other platform.

If you do that you should also create a fourth non-java project that is just responsible for building the java projects. It would contain a common build file with usual commands (compile, package etc) and third-party jars. The build files for your java projects would import the common build file so there is no duplication of ant targets.

Comment: Thank you for your input Kevin. What I forgot to mention is that the one project I currently have is opened in 2 eclipse versions (each seperate version has some minor changes). One is in eclipse with the blackberry plugin, while the other is in an other eclipse which supports midlet projects. There must be some way to share this code and only adjusting the build file. No? I hope someone understands what I'm trying to say.

Comment: That's an interesting setup, but you should still be able to arrange things like I've suggested. You could have 2 instances of Eclipse open on two different workspaces and use File->Import->General->Existing projects to pull in the appropriate platform project plus the common project. I'm guessing you've tried to install the 2 plugins into the same eclipse instance.